# Entering protected mode reboots

Tags: protected-mode

For understanding the working of the operating system I have made a simpel bootloader which loads a small test application for testing protected mode etc. After the bootsector has been loaded at 0x7c00 the bootloader loads the test code at segment 0x2000 and starts the first instruction. But when I try to enter the protected mode the systems reboots. Can anyone help me with this problem?

This is my code at section 0x2000

```
    BITS 16

; Entering_ProtectedMode:   

    cli                                             
    mov ax, 2000h
    mov ss, ax                                      
    mov sp, 0FFFFh
    sti                                             
    cld                                             

    mov ax, 2000h                                   
    mov ds, ax                                      
    mov es, ax                                      
    mov fs, ax                                      
    mov gs, ax

    ;xor ax, ax
    ;mov ds, ax              ; update data segment

    cli                     ; clear interrupts

    lgdt [gdtr]             ; load GDT from GDTR (see gdt_32.inc)

    call OpenA20Gate        ; open the A20 gate 
    call EnablePMode        ; jumps to ProtectedMode

OpenA20Gate:
    in al, 0x93         ; switch A20 gate via fast A20 port 92
    or al, 2            ; set A20 Gate bit 1
    and al, ~1          ; clear INIT_NOW bit
    out 0x92, al
    ret

EnablePMode:
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG : ProtectedMode

;*********************************
;* Global Descriptor Table (GDT) *
;*********************************
NULL_DESC:
    dd 0            ; null descriptor
    dd 0

CODE_DESC:
    dw 0xFFFF       ; limit low
    dw 0            ; base low
    db 0            ; base middle
    db 10011010b    ; access
    db 11001111b    ; granularity
    db 0            ; base high

DATA_DESC:
    dw 0xFFFF       ; limit low
    dw 0            ; base low
    db 0            ; base middle
    db 10010010b    ; access
    db 11001111b    ; granularity
    db 0            ; base high

gdtr:
    dw gdtr - NULL_DESC - 1 ; length of GDT
    dd NULL_DESC   ; base of GDT

CODE_SEG equ CODE_DESC - NULL_DESC
DATA_SEG equ DATA_DESC - NULL_DESC  

;******************
;* Protected Mode *
;******************
    BITS 32

ProtectedMode:

    .halt:
        jmp .halt

    ;mov     ax, 10h
    ;mov     ds, ax ; update data segment
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
OpenA20Gate:
in al, 0x92; instead of 0x93; switch A20 gate via fast A20 port 92
or al, 2            ; set A20 Gate bit 1
and al, ~1          ; clear INIT_NOW bit
out 0x92, al
ret

EnablePMode:
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1
mov cr0, eax
```

......

;CODE_SEG must be equal 8 like "8:ProtectedMode". 8 points at the first descriptor of the GDT. 16 bit: 15-3 - index in the GDT (0 for the zero descriptor, 1 for the first descriptor - code, 2 for the second descriptor - data), 2 - the table indicator (0 for the GDT, 1 for the LDT), 1-0 - RPL (the request privilege level).

```
jmp CODE_SEG:ProtectedMode
```